# Loop hole in loop's logic

Tags: java, exception, do-while

I am trying a program on exception handling to calculate height in centimeters.

```
import java.util.*;
class Ex{
private static double height(int feet, int inches) throws Exception{
        if(feet < 0 || inches < 0)
            throw new Exception("Please enter positive values only.");
        return (feet * 30.48) + (inches * 2.54);
    }

 public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
 boolean continueLoop = true;

 do{
     try
     {
         System.out.println("Enter height in feet:");
         int feet=scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println("and in inches:");
         int inches = scanner.nextInt();
         double result = height(feet,inches);
         System.out.println("Result:"+result+" cm");
         continueLoop = false;
     }
     catch(InputMismatchException e){
         System.out.println("You must enter integers. Please try again.");
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }while(continueLoop);
}
}
```

When an InputMismatchException occurs, the program enters into an infinite loop. What is the fault in my logic here? What change(s) should I do?

Comment: what are inputs ? possiblely you are entering double or string on console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `scanner.nextLine()` to your catch blocks, in order to consume the rest of the current line, so that `nextInt` can attempt to read new input from the next line.

```
 do{
     try
     {
         System.out.println("Enter height in feet:");
         int feet=scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println("and in inches:");
         int inches = scanner.nextInt();
         double result = height(feet,inches);
         System.out.println("Result:"+result+" cm");
         continueLoop = false;
     }
     catch(InputMismatchException e){
         System.out.println("You must enter integers. Please try again.");
         scanner.nextLine();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         scanner.nextLine();
     }
 }while(continueLoop);
```

Comment: What's the use of scanner.nextLine() in catch and why it's not needed in the second catch?

Comment: @Leo scanner.nextInt() reads only part of a line. Now, if you input something that's not an integer, and call nextInt, you'll get InputMismatchException. In that case, you have to get rid of the line that contains the invalid input before trying to read an integer again. That's what scanner.nextLine() does. Now that I see what other exceptions you may throw, it looks like you also need it in the second catch block. Otherwise, you'll hit the same problem when you enter a negative integer.